# Attaching IAM role to Neptune cluster using cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, cluster-computing, aws-cloudformation, amazon-neptune

I want to attach the role I am creating in CFN script to the neptune DB cluster. Following is my code where I am creating a cluster and a NeptuneRole.

I want to attach the created role to the above cluster. How can I do that?
Also, how do I create a cluster snapshot via CFN?

```
Resources:
  # Creating Neptune DB Cluster
  NeptuneDBCluster:
    Type: AWS::Neptune::DBCluster
    Properties:
      DBClusterIdentifier:   
        !Join
          - ''
          - - !Ref enviroment
            - '-neptune-graphcluster-'
            - !FindInMap [RegionShortname, !Ref "AWS::Region", RN]
            
      DBClusterParameterGroupName: !Ref NeptuneDBClusterParameterGroup
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref NeptuneDBSubnetGroup
      BackupRetentionPeriod: 1
      VpcSecurityGroupIds: !Ref SecurityGroupIds
      IamAuthEnabled: false
      Preferre dBackupWindow: "07:14-07:44"
      

 
  # Creating Netpune IAM Role to get NeptuneFullAccess
  NeptuneRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName:  
        !Join
            - ''
            - - !Ref enviroment
              - '-neptune-role-'
              - !FindInMap [RegionShortname, !Ref "AWS::Region", RN]
              
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - ec2.amazonaws.com
            - rds.amazonaws.com
          Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns: arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/NeptuneFullAccess
```

Comment: Quick question - Why are you attaching an IAM role with NeptuneFullAccess to the cluster? That does not sound like a valid use case to me. The roles to "attach" to a cluster are usually for making the DB cluster access an external AWS Service. For eg: A role with S3 access would be needed to do bulk load. NeptuneFullAccess policy only gives you access to perform management API calls (like creating a cluster, instance etc), and attaching a role with that permission to a Neptune cluster is actually not going to help with anything.

Comment: Did you have any updates to share on this Q?